# What does the animated class do?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

```
   $("button").addClass("animated bounce");                 
   $(".well").addClass("animated shake");                                
   $("#target3").addClass("fadeOut");
```

What does the animated class do?
When I take out the "animated" class, the button won't bounce and the well wouldn't shake.
Is the "animated" class part of Bootstrap or jQuery?

I am a beginner and if my question sounds silly, sorry in advance.

Comment: The CSS definitions for those classes could literally come from anywhere. Check your own code to see what libraries you're including or even your own CSS. They don't appear to be a standard part of Bootstrap and are definitely not part of jQuery

Comment: You can do an inspect element, find the class and you can see its css properties.

Comment: look at your browser inspector (`F12` key)

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.. thanks to the people who had helped me in the comments section.
Turns out the "animated" class comes from the Animate.css library:
https://animate.style/

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding an example of the library and how it fixed the problem.